# Como criptografar imagens com algoritmo RC5 em Java

Tags: java, exceção, criptografia

Estou tentando utilizar o algoritmo RC5 com a classe cipher do Java, mas ele está retornando um erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class EncriptaDecriptaRC5 {

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
    SecretKey secretKey = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;

    public EncriptaDecriptaRC5() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC5");  //Cria a chave
        keyGenerator.init(128);    // 128 - 192 - 256
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        System.out.println(secretKey.getEncoded().length);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC5");     //Cria uma instância da cifra mencionando o nome do algoritmo de criptografia
    }

    void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws InvalidKeyException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        File rawFile = new File(srcPath);
        File imagemEncriptada = new File(destPath);
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);   //Inicializa o cipher para encriptar
        inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile);       //Inicializa o input e o output streams
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(imagemEncriptada);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));   //Para criptografar/descriptografar vários blocos usa-se o método update(). 
            outStream.flush();
        }
        outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());                 //Depois de tudo feito chamamos o método doFinal(). 
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }

    void decrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) throws InvalidKeyException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        File encryptedFile = new File(srcPath);
        File decryptedFile = new File(destPath);
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey); //Inicializa o cipher para decriptografar
        inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile); //Inicializa o input e o output streams
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
            outStream.flush();
        }
        outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
}
```

O erro que o programa retorna é este:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RC5 KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at Simetrico.EncriptaDecriptaRC5.<init>(EncriptaDecriptaRC5.java:23)
    at Simetrico.TesteRC5.main(TesteRC5.java:27)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Pelo jeito sua JVM não dá suporte a esse algoritmo. Precisa ser o RC5? Eu encontrei poucas informações sobre ele, provavelmente pelo fato dele ser relativamente antigo e aparentemente pouco usado. P.S. Você possui o Java Cryptographic Extensions (JCE) instalado?

Comment: Sim, precisa ser o RC5, os outros algoritmos implementados pela Cipher eu já consegui, só falta este. Também encontrei pouca informação sobre a implementação dele. Eu preciso fazer um comparativo dos algoritmos, por isso, mesmo que antigo, preciso dos resultados dele. Já instalei a versão do JCE para politica de segurança do Java.

Comment: A JCE instalada foi: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124438/520779) o JCE provê suporte para RC5, mas nenhuma implementação concreta do mesmo. Não tenho como confirmar a veracidade dessa informação, mas pela sua exceção esse parece ser mesmo o caso. Um provedor externo pode ser necessário, e a sugestão dessa mesma resposta é o [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).

Após [instalá-lo](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) você precisa [configurá-lo](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) dessa forma antes de usá-lo:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Alternativamente, adicione uma entrada em `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` para uma instalação estática global:

```
security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Trocando `N` pelo próximo número da lista (lá deve ter várias entradas do tipo `security.provider.x`, onde `x` é um número).

Depois disso, seu código tal como está deverá funcionar normalmente, ou ao menos não terá mais esse erro específico. Não tenho certeza se a forma como você está criando o `Cipher` está correta ou não, acho que também é necessário especificar o [modo de operação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28criptografia%29) e, se aplicável, o [*padding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) (ex.: `Cipher.getInstance("RC5/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`).

Comment: Obrigada @mgibsonbr era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Agora está funcionando.
Só algumas considerações: se for colocado no código: `import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` não é necessário configurar o arquivo java.security (Eu pelo menos não consegui configurar direto neste arquivo), tive de instalar o pacote referente a minha versão do java (https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) - baixei e salvei em `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`